# How to control fan speed in Dell Inspiron 5010 (15R)?

Tags: dell, fan, sensors

How can I control fan speed on Inspiron 15R? I installed i8kutils as instructed on ubuntuforums but don't know how to use it. Fan makes quite a noise and runs all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So doing the research on this, it looks like the way to control the fan is to issue the following command:

```
i8kctl fan R L
```

Where R is the right fan mode and L is the left fan mode. The modes are as follows:

```
0  turn the fan off
1  set low speed
2  set high speed
-  don't change the state of this fan
```

You should install `sensors-applet` which contains an applet you can add to your gnome panel. This keeps track of the temperature of your cpu and system and you should certainly keep a track on it if you are going to change the fan speed. Once you've got the applet installed, you just have to right click on your gnome panel and click `Add to panel...` look down the list for `Hardware Sensors Applet`

Comment: If the info answers your question, then please set as answered and mark me up. See the controls on the left of the answer.