# the "additional drivers" shows nothing

Tags: drivers, dell, overheating, inspiron

I started using **Ubuntu 32 bit** last week. I love it but I recognized there was a problem with the **cooling** system. the fan doesn't stop and slightly loud all the time (that wasn't the case while running with windows 7).
I told a friend who claimed that it should be a **drivers** problem.
My machine is dell **inspiron n5110** and the official site recommends **win 7 64 bit** only. there's no support for linux. ([the page showing the machine drivers and system recommendation](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/ServiceTag/30wmnt1)
I tried to fix the problem using the "**additional drivers**", it opens but it shows nothing (no drivers to activate, just the help and the close buttons)
is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your CPU is running on maximum performance all the time and generating a lot of heat, hence the fan doesn't stop.
I suggest you to install [Jupiter](http://www.jupiterapplet.org/index.html), as it will show your CPU temperature and also let you choose which performance profile you want.
Here's how you [install and configure Jupiter in Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/jupiter-light-weight-power-and-hardware-control-applet.html#more-13276).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing i8kutils, and check out the information in this post [How to control fan speed in Dell Inspiron 5010 (15R)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22049/how-to-control-fan-speed-in-dell-inspiron-5010-15r)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.