# No fan control for CPU fan

Tags: dell, fan

I am using a Dell Inspiron 15 Laptop, with Ubuntu Installed on my WD Passport partition as a portable installation.

On the CPU Fan, it never looks like it has any control over itself. At a constant speed and noise, it keeps on running no matter whether I use the system or not.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: do you have dual graphics card (nvidia optimus or amd hybird)? open a terminal and post result of `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to control fan speed in Dell Inspiron 5010 (15R)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22049/how-to-control-fan-speed-in-dell-inspiron-5010-15r)

Comment: Hi Web-E, here is the output.

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Caicos [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/516067/persistent-high-fan-speed-ubuntu-14-04/537538#537538
Try the solution listed here.