# Fan running on high nonstop

Tags: 16.04, hardware, fan, fancontrol

I have an asus zenbook with Ubuntu 16.04 installed.

I'm having an issue where the fans are always running on high. Does anyone know how I can resolve this? I have found a number of related topics, but none that seemed to apply to my specific situation.

The only thing I tried previously was an Asus laptop package that wouldn't install on my computer.

All my temps are in the low to mid range, so I don't think it's an issue with CPU usage.

`dpkg -l intel-microcode`:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                   Version          Architecture     Description
+++-======================-================-================-=================================================
ii  intel-microcode        3.20151106.1     amd64            Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs
```

`dpkg -l thermald`:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                   Version          Architecture     Description
+++-======================-================-================-=================================================
ii  thermald               1.5-2ubuntu2     amd64            Thermal monitoring and controlling daemon
```

Comment: Have you attempted to get `fancontrol` working? Does changing CPU governors do anything?

Comment: running `pwmconfig` I get "There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0"

Comment: Many fans are manufacturer-controlled/specific and can't always be controlled by Ubuntu. There are some things you can attempt: http://askubuntu.com/questions/516067/persistent-high-fan-speed-ubuntu-14-04. Both answers listed may provide a solution. I also recommend switching between various CPU governors and checking for any improved results.

Comment: Thanks, neither of those answers helped though, unfortunately.

Comment: Any options in the BIOS of interest? Updating the BIOS? What happens when you boot a LiveUSB?

Comment: Nothing in the bios that I could find. I'll have to try booting from usb  some other time.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include which "related topics" you already addressed that didn't fit your situation? Thank you, this will help us avoid providing you solutions that you've already tried.

Comment: It's been about a month since I last tried to solve this. I added the only thing I remember from then.

Comment: Check the ASUS web site for a BIOS update for your model. You have Intel processors, yes? Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `dpkg -l intel-microcode` and `dpkg -l thermald`.

Comment: Do you have suitable graphics drivers installed? Otherwise this may just be CPU or GPU running at full speed.