# Ubuntu start and fan problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, fan

I have some problem with Ubuntu on my brand new win10 Asus laptop, I am new to Linux, so really need your help.

About my laptop: Win10 64bit, i7, 8GB, 128G SSD + 1TB HDD, Nvidia 950M graphic card, brand new, no personal apps/files.

Before installation I encountered a problem booting from usb drive, the Ubuntu 5 point loading page freezes at loading. And then I used UUI to re-do the usb drive and then it passes.

I installed Ubuntu on the 1TB HDD with 30GB root, 300G home and 16GB swap. Leaving Win10 on the 128GSSD (dual boot). Installation process is smooth, but right after install, I reboot the laptop and it freezes at Ubuntu loading (the purple gradient blank screen before the text loading page) There is nothing I can do, so I force the laptop to shut down and then restart.

And then it is like I can only get into Ubuntu every other time, 1 out of 2 times it will stuck at loading, the gradient purple blank screen before text loading show up.

When I get into Ubuntu, the laptop fan seems to be always running at the maximum speed, so I googled some fan control advice. First I followed this tutorial and did:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=!Windows 2012"
```

[Persistent High-Fan Speed Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516067/persistent-high-fan-speed-ubuntu-14-04/537538#537538)

but the problem is not solved, so I installed the Laptop Mode Tools as recommended [here on ubuntuhandbook.org](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/07/laptop-mode-tools-1-67-ubuntu-14-04/)

And then I just can't get into Ubuntu and get the error message (the fan is still running fast)：

```
tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0xfed400B0-0xfed40fff]
```

I managed to get to the root from grub menu, and removed laptop mode tools and gksu, and when I reboot the error message is still there but I can get into Ubuntu. But still stuck at loading page almost every other time.

And then I got frustrated and completely removed Ubuntu partition. Now I wanted to give it another try but when I try to boot from usb, it gets stuck at loading page again, almost every time (5 points loading page).

So, why does it always freeze at the loading page (the 5 points indicator page when I boot from usb) (the purple gradient blank screen before the text loading page after installation)? How can I solve the fan problem?

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. It was connected with skylake processor architecture. After A LOT OF tries found out that installing ubuntu mate 16.04(not .10) with nvidia-prime solves the issue.

Comment: could you elaborate? What hardware did you resolve this on? Does it only work on MATE (what if OP doesn't want to use MATE?) How do we set up Nvidia Prime?