# Macbook pro retina fans running crazy after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, graphics, macbook-pro, fancontrol

I recently upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04.
My fans are running constantly now.  They were fine prior.
I have exhausted all online advice on how to install tools, etc.
Nothing works.  Any suggestions on what changed, and how to fix it ?
Thanks!

Comment: Hmmmm.... does this macbook have dedicated graphics? If so, can you post the specs?

Comment: It is NVE7 graphics.  Intel® Core™ i7-4870HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz × 8

Comment: Maybe duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029007/349837). Please edit your post to add the output of `inxi -SMIG -! 31 && journalctl -b0 -k -p3 && grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub`.