# i8kctl not working for Dell Inspiron fan control

Tags: 16.04, power-management, fan, fancontrol

I am trying to control the fan speed manually using the i8kctl package for dell laptops.

System - Ubuntu 16.04, 4.17.19-041719-generic
Dell 7567 Inspiron

I followed the instructions in https://askubuntu.com/a/398635 answer, succesfully disabling the BIOS fan control.

However, when I do

```
ik8ctl fan 2 2
```

The output is 
    `-1 -1`

I think this means that the fan speed setting was not successful.

ik8ctl fan
returns `0 0` indicating that no fans are on, as the BIOS fan control has been disabled.

I have no issues turning BIOS control on, but I need the fan speed at max at times, which the BIOS is not doing due to some weird reasons.

Why is am8ctl not able to set the fan speeds?

**UPDATE**:
Running as root

```
sudo ik8ctl fan 2 2
```

returns 0 0, rather than the earlier -1 -1. Still doesn't quite work as expected.

**UPDATE2**
Looking at this bug report solution (https://bugs.launchpad.net/i8kutils/+bug/1620580), I force loaded the modules

```
sudo rmmod dell-smm-hwmon
$ sudo modprobe dell-smm-hwmon restricted=0
```

The fan control works now for a limited time (1 second). Looks like the bias still takes control after for some reason.

Comment: I can't help you at the moment. I'm on a Vostro 5481 w. Ubuntu 19.10 and I have the same issue. I want to control my fan speeds but did not succeed yet. Whatever you find, let me / us know. Thanks!

BTW: I verified that I actually CAN control the fan by using `while true; do sudo ./i8kctl fan 0 1; done;` - BIOS just grabs control every second

Comment: I also tried with https://github.com/TomFreudenberg/dell-bios-fan-control and https://github.com/clopez/dellfan but no luck. :(

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution for my Vostro 5481. It might work for you (and others) as well.

**Required**

```
git clone https://github.com/TomFreudenberg/dell-bios-fan-control.git
cd dell-bios-fan-control
make
sudo ./dell-bios-fan-control 0
```

If you get an error like this

```
ioperm:: Operation not permitted 
ioperm:: Operation not permitted [1] 
4701 segmentation fault
```

you need to go to your BIOS/UEFI and disable SECURE BOOT. Then run the command again. Output should now be `BIOS CONTROL DISABLED`.

**Quick testing**
You can now go and check solutions for controlling the fan that suite your needs. If you want to quickly test, you can use i8kutils:

```
git clone https://github.com/vitorafsr/i8kutils
cd i8kutils
make
sudo ./i8kctl fan 2 2
```

Your fan should now run at the highest possible settings without the BIOS/UEFI interfering.

**Controlling the fan in day to day business**
Now that your BIOS/UEFI is no longer controlling the fan, you have to take care of it on your own. I'd suggest https://linux.die.net/man/8/fancontrol for this. It can easily be configured using `pwmonfig` (which ships with it) and adds itself as a system service.

**Big THANKS**
Shoutout to Tom Freudenberg for creating `dell-bios-fan-control` and for pointing me to disabling `SECURE_BOOT` when I got the `Operation not permitted` error.

https://github.com/TomFreudenberg
 https://askubuntu.com/users/293845/tom-freudenberg.

Comment: Thanks, disabling BIOS control helped me. Otherwise, it was slowing down the fan speed when the CPU temp was 70°. Does it also mean that BIOS will not spin the fan before the OS is loaded?

Comment: I'm using i8kmon installed with apt-get. Is there any advantage of using fancontrol and pwmonfig over i8kmon?

Answer (score 0):

in my case dell-bios-fan-control didn't work initially, after struggling for a bit I realized for some reason `sudo ./dell-bios-fan-control 0` works after running make manually, as opposed to `sudo dell-bios-fan-control 0` (due to ioperm). not sure why (maybe in between I disabled idrac, that could have been the cause as well) but anyway, then I was able to set the fan speed permanently to 0, which caused my system to crash, in the end I did below which worked (Dell R415 poweredge, so pretty old server)

```
sudo apt-get install ipmitool   # install
sudo ipmitool sdr type fan      # check fan speed
sudo ipmitool raw 0x30 0x30 0x01 0x00       # disable automatic control
sudo ipmitool raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff 0x00  # set fan speed to 0x00
```