# Fan not work on Dell precision 3510

Tags: dell, fan, overheating

I have a dell precision 3510 with one fan and My fan speed is 0 rpm all the time.

```
sensors | grep fan
fan1:           0 RPM
```

Also when I use i8kmon:

```
temp, left fan state, right fan state, ac state: 40 -1 1 0
```

I follow this guide to control my fan speed [Fan speed control issues on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269769/fan-speed-control-issues-on-ubuntu) . However, when I:

```
$ make
cc -o dell-bios-fan-control dell-bios-fan-control.c
make: cc: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:6: dell-bios-fan-control] Error 127
```

and when I use
`sudo i8kctl fan 2 2` or any other speed the fan spin for one second only and then stopped.

On windows, I used a tool that overridden the bios setting after I disable the secure boot. but on Linux. I can stay for only 15 min before the laptop completely freeze.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

and everything works fine.
To clarify:

first, you have to

```
 sudo apt install build-essential
```

then

```
git clone https://github.com/TomFreudenberg/dell-bios-fan-control.git
cd dell-bios-fan-control
make
sudo dell-bios-fan-control 0
```

then

```
git clone https://github.com/vitorafsr/i8kutils
cd i8kutils
make
sudo i8kctl fan 1 1
```

to make it work at lower speed and `sudo i8kctl fan 2 2`. If it's stopped randomly (which happens to me several times). you need to check whether one of the fans was corrupted or in my case was completely unplugged (which I don't know actually).
to check you can use `sudo i8kmon`. The -1 means completely unplugged and 0 means not working.